# How to get exact values of the foreignkeys in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
class Mio_terminal(models.Model):
    terminal = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    gate = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    gate_status = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'open') #open, occupied, under_maintenance
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['terminal', 'gate']]



class Mio_flight_schedule(models.Model):
    fact_guid = models.CharField(max_length=64, primary_key=True)
    airline_flight_key = models.ForeignKey(Mio_airline, related_name = 'flight_key',  on_delete = models.CASCADE)    
    source = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    arrival_departure = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    time =  models.DateTimeField()
    gate_code = models.ForeignKey(Mio_terminal, related_name = 'terminal_gate', null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    baggage_carousel = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    terminal_code = models.ForeignKey(Mio_terminal, related_name = 'airport_terminal', null = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

These are models for terminal and flight schedules.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ62t.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWVNA.png)

I want to have a terminal name and gate code instead of the object ...

I know we can get this by using the **str** method in models....but we get only a single value for this...not more than one

I want to use the terminal as a foreign_key for terminal_code in the flight_schedule model and the gate as a gate_code.I am getting terminal_code _gate code as a string ...but it's not reflecting as separate entities...I don't want the combined string.....I want when I click on the terminal ...only the terminal dropdown should display..and the same for the gate code

please let me know how should I deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the display name of models in django admin interface by using `def __str__(self)`.

So for in your code add this function after the `Mio_terminal` class :

```
class Mio_terminal(models.Model):
    terminal = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    gate = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    gate_status = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = 'open') #open, occupied, under_maintenance
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [['terminal', 'gate']]
    
    # add this
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.terminal+' '+self.gate)
```

Comment: Better to use f-strings so `return f"{self.terminal} {self.gate}"`

Comment: hi....i want to use terminal as a foreign_key for terminal_code in flight_schedule model and gate as a gate_code.when i am trying to do changes suggested by u...i am getting terminal_code _gate code as a string ...but its not reflecting as a seperate entities....i dont want the string.....i want when i click on terminal ...only terminal dropdown should display..and same for the gate code

Comment: @swapnilwagh can you illustrate the desired output?